# i want to display it according to category but i'm stuck

Tags: php, jquery, html

i want to display it according to category but i'm stuck..is it ok to use both jquery and php at the same time..sorry im just a noobie..

```
<select name="category" id="category" >
<option value="All Student">All Student<?php echo "(".$count.")";?></option>
<option value="By Name">By Name</option>
<option value="By Date">By Date</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#category').change(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == 'All Student') {
                <?php 
                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_student WHERE (teacher_id ='".$_SESSION['idnum']."') ORDER BY firstname");
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){         //another way to get the data from database.........
                        $idnum = $row['idnum'];                 //getting the GroupID.....                                 display
                        $firstname = $row['firstname'];
                        $lastname = $row['lastname'];
                        $midname = $row['midname'];
                    }
                ?>                                                                                                      
                <table>
                    <td>
                        <p class="my_studz"><?php echo $firstname ." ".$lastname ." ".$midname?></p>
                    </td>
                </table>
                <?php } ?> 
            } else if ($(this).val() == 'By Name') {
                <?php 
                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_student WHERE (teacher_id ='".$_SESSION['idnum']."') ORDER BY Date_Created");
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){         //another way to get the data from database.........
                        $idnum = $row['idnum'];                 //getting the GroupID.....                                 display
                        $firstname = $row['firstname'];
                        $lastname = $row['lastname'];
                        $midname = $row['midname'];
                    }
                ?>                                                                                                      
                <table>
                    <td>
                        <p class="my_studz"><?php echo $firstname ." ".$lastname ." ".$midname?></p>
                    </td>
                </table>
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: 'it'. What is 'it'? You can use PHP and jQuery at the same time, but not like this, you need AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

Php is a **server**-sided scripting language. If you use it correctly, it generates a valid html-page. If you want to execute inline-javascript, you have to make sure that your php generates valid javascript too.

Javascript is a **client**-sided scripting language. It is executed long after php is done with it's job. If your php generates invalid javascript, then javascript will do nothing.

So as an answer to your question *"is it ok to use both jquery and php at the same time"*: It is impossible to execute jquery and php at the same time. Php is executed first. Whatever that generates is sent to the browser and if it contains any javascript, that is executed. You can use php anywhere on your page, and you can generate javascript with it. Please remember to ALWAYS properly escape data you put in your javascript via php. The names `';alert('xss');'` or `";alert('xss');"` should not give you a popup with xss in it.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you need to display a table based on the selected index of the select named "category".

Note that PHP is executed on the server and jQuery, on the client PC. So, No, they do not run at the same time.

Here is how you can make PHP and jQuery work for you.

1. Your script should contain only javascript code that hides or shows a table according to its id when the select's value changes.
2. Move the PHP code that outputs each of the tables outside the script. Give each an id thus `<table id="allstudents"> <table id="byname"> <table id="bydate">`
3. Hide all tables using jQuery thus `$("#allstudents").hide(); $("#byname").hide(); $("#bydate").hide()`;

That should work.